# How can I share my workspace with two platforms (OS X and Win)?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have a my java workspace stored in Dropbox. I have Eclipse galileo on my Windows PC. I have a Mac and I want to build my application also with this new computer. So I have installed Eclipse galileo, Dropbox. Now there is a problem when I try to open one project. The problem is:

- Path of Library (in windows I have library on D:\Dropbox\workspace\library; in Mac I have user\dropbox\workspace\library)
- Version of JVM (in my windows pc I have JVM 1.7 and in my Mac I have 1.6

I have read some article to do this, and in one of these I have read to use selected sync of Dropbox and not sync .metadata folder. I have do this and one problem is fixed, now when I try to open the eclipse I don't see some project modify, open closed. Then it's ok.

The two problems that I have described above. So, how can I share my workspace and use it on both the computers?

Comment: Note: Java 7 and 8 are both available for Macs from the Oracle [download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a 5 year old post [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/476114/vc/sharing-Eclipse-workspace-platforms-metadata).  The conclusion it is not really possible and practical to have one workspace shared between the platforms. Which problem are you trying to solve? The general way would be to get a repository e.g. git or svn, store your application there and keep in in-sync with different eclipse installations via versioning plugins.